# Slice an array in Vue using GraphQL data layer

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, gridsome

I am trying to slice an array of items in Vue
here is my code

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in Items" :item="item" :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</div>
</template>

<page-query>
  query {
    count
    items {
       id
       name
    }
  }
</page-query>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
          items: Array,
        }
        computed: {
          Items() {
            return this.items.slice(0, 4);
          },
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see I am slicing the array by 4.
In my API data I have a "count" object that returns a number I need to use to slice the items but I cant figure out a way how. Could you please give me a hint how to use count data instead of hardcoded number 4?

Comment: are you using gridsome?

Comment: Yes I'm using gridsome :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`limit`](https://gridsome.org/docs/querying-data/#querying-collections) should help you

```
<page-query>
  query {
    count
    items(limit: 4) {
       id
       name
    }
  }
</page-query>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but limit is a hardcoded number again. I am trying to dynamically slice. In my query I have "count" that returns a number. I need to use this number to slice or limit the array.